# Drawing buttons in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

my idea is to add different buttons for drawing interaction in OL3 such as :

---

`<button id="Point" onclick="addInteractions(Point)">button1</button>
<button id="Polygon" onclick="drawPolygon(Polygon)">button2</button
<button id="LineString" onclick="drawLine(LineString)">button2</button>
var drawstyle = new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'}),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#ffcc33', width: 2}),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({radius: 7, fill: new ol.style.Fill({        color: '#ffcc33'}) })

      });
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({source: source, style: drawstyle)};
function addInteractions(str) {
        var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
          source: source,
          type: str
        });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
}`

---

on the official site of OL, all examples used the html select tag, but I don't want to use it. 
can someone help me please !

Answer (score 1):

`Point` is not defined when you call `onclick="addInteractions(Point)"`.

Instead of `onclick="addInteractions(Point)"` you should use `onclick='addInteractions("Point")'`. This second call passes the string `Point` as expected by the function `addInteractions`.

You should also call the same function `addInteractions` on the other two buttons, right? It should be:

```
<button id="Point" onclick='addInteractions("Point")'>button1</button>
<button id="Polygon" onclick='addInteractions("Polygon")'>button2</button>
<button id="LineString" onclick='addInteractions("LineString")'>button2</button>
```

To get a better answer, you should copy and paste the errors you got on the browser's console.